# Alternative to "New Close Reason" -- a Basic Electronics Commun Wiki Series

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Having just posted [Proposal for new close reason -- "Low expertise", "Too Basic"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5540), another approach springs to mind.

Instead of answering such questions, we would answer them in a Basic Electronics Community Wiki -- or a set of such questions -- and then close the original as a duplicate.  Perhaps a "Basic Electronics -- how to drive high current devices with a microcontroller or Arduino"  would be a good wiki question.

If we tag this "Basic Electronics Wiki", we'd always be able to find it easily if we police the tag.

Comment: This is exactly how the system already works, so your proposing nothing?

Comment: @Passerby If that's how it wors, find the basic post I refer to above and vote to close the question as a duplicate. It only counts if it takes about 30 seconds.

Comment: I googled "electrical engineering wiki" and couldn't find it... link @Passerby? About 75% of the questions I see here are "Help me wire this relay to my million-volt transformer" or "LED resistor value needed" or "Can I reverse this 220VAC blender motor?" types of questions; which are fine, but could all be answered in one "wiki for beginners." That would free us veterans for handling juicier questions and giving those the attention they deserve.